# JAXB / MOXy: How to set which xpath impl to use?

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, implementation, moxy

I use MOXy's `@XmlPath("/foo/bar[@baz]")`.

Elsewhere in the app I need XSLT 2.0 so I included Saxon HA 9.5 on my classpath.
But that caused the XPath fail (doesn't find the nodes, unlike JDK's implementation).

**How can I set for MOXy which XML / XPath impl to use?**

Currently I use `jaxb.properties` next to JAXB bean's `.class`, but I'm okay to create the marshaller with some factory options or such.

**Bonus question:** I think the problem with XPath is that the XML file uses namespaces, `<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0"> ...`
How can I make Saxon ignore namespaces in XPath? (without rewriting the XPath expression).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this question. actually, I am also trying to do something similar but for some reason, it's not working as expected. I tried the things mentioned in this answer as well. I tried this approach and the example from the authors blog but still the `JAXB Marshalling` does not work as expected with `@XmlPath`. Seems like the XML produced with and without `@XmlPath` are the same. Can you please once look into this example and provide your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500565/xmlpath-has-no-impact-during-the-jaxb-marshalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s `@XmlPath` annotation supports a subset of the XPath specification. The XPath handling is done by MOXy itself.  The following concepts are supported:

- Attribute - `@id`
- Element - `address`
- Element by Position - `address[1]`
- Element by Predicate - `address[@type='mailing']`
- Element Text - `name/text()`
- Text - `text()`
- Self - `.`
- Combination - `personal-info/name[2]/text()`

For namespace qualified nodes, the prefixes defined in the `@XmlNs` annotations can be used to qualify the XPath fragments.  Unqualified fragments will assumed to be in the namespace specified using `@XmlSchema`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Comment: Thanks, actually the XPath exception was coming from a different place.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this wasn't MOXy related. It was my code using XPath. So I ended up with

```
//XPathFactory xpf = XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance();
//XPathFactory xpf = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl();
XPathFactory xpf = new com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl();
```

This will complain

```
com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

but works.

Regarding namespaces, here's a [discussion on ignoring namespaces](http://saxon-xslt-and-xquery-processor.13853.n7.nabble.com/XPath-and-skipping-namespaces-td10633.html).

Comment: You can eliminate the "internal proprietary API" warning by passing the `-XDignore.symbol.file` command-line option to javac.  (Doing so is not recommended, though.)